# Reading whole pages from a word document and setting each page as an element to an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so I am pretty new to coding and I just followed some YouTube tutorials etc to learn some Python with pygame. I have came across a problem I want to solve at work. I would like to make a program that reads a word document with around 100 pages and insert a one page word document in between every page. I was assuming to set the 100 page document to an array full of each page and running a for loop that creates a new document and adds the first element of the array being the first page and then inserts the one page that will be the same for each therefore giving me the final product. I just can not figure out how to set an array with each page as an element. Anything helps.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow, you might have better luck at https://reddit.com/r/learnpython

Comment: Please provide what you did and where are you facing problem. Don't just ask how to do it without trying.

Comment: Sorry thanks for the feedback